# Exception: Invalid field X__c for SObject Y__c

Tags: apex, pageblocktable, database, repeat

I have below VF Page.

```
 <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CPAT_accounts}" var="c">
            <apex:repeat value="{!excelFields}" var="f">
                <apex:column value="{!c[f]}" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

It's corresponding controller has below **excelFields** to show.

```
public List<String> excelFields {
        get {
            if (excelFields == null) {
                excelFields = new List<String>();
                    planfields = [select Plan__c from AB__c where Name='XX' and Time_Period__c='Q2 2018'].Plan_Fields__c;

                List<String> fieldlist= planfields.split(',');
                for (String fsm : fieldlist) {
                    excelFields.add(fsm);
                }
            }

            return excelFields;
        }

        private set;
    }
```

Here planfields contains the field names to be queried on object Y__c.
Although 'X__c' a value there in planfields and also a custom field existing in Y__c object has proper FLS for the logged in User I get the error as mentioned in the header.

Can someone please let me know where I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have any extra spaces or something, perhaps? This code looks fine at first glance, so I suspect it's a data issue.

Comment: Could you include the actual Dynamic SOQL query as well? Or are you using `addFields()` to populate the object?